# How to specify SQL-value through a DIV?

Tags: php, sql

I'm still battling my way through a tough and endless quest; creating a **Football Betting System**. This is not only to *actually* create something, but also to improve my skills.

In this project I use (if to any use):

- **WordPress**
- **Navicat**
- **SQL**
- **PHP**

I have a database table called "Bets". It contains the following columns;

- **ID** (just to assign each match a continuously growing number)
- **gameid** (the id of the current match)
- **userid** (the users id)
- **homebet** (the users homebet)
- **awaybet** (the users awaybet)

I've created a PHP-based form, where the user can input two numbers - **homebet** and **awaybet** - corresponding to the goalscorings in a match. Through there, an **insert.php**-file, which gets called everytime the user presses the submit-button, snatches the users id - **userid** - and of course assigns a continous number to the newly created bet.

My problem is then; I have no idea how I should assign each new match posted on the site - this is done by calling information via a **SQL Select**-statement - with a **gameid**.

**THE PHP FORM**

```
<form action="/scripts/insert.php" method="post" name="gameid"> <!-- Not sure if name="gameid" serves a purpose or just a test - I'm sorry. -->
        <div id="betting-structure">
            <div class="main-betting-bg">
                <div class="right-betting-team">
                    <h8 class="centering-teamname1">Arsenal</h8><img src="/images/pl-logo-arsnl.png"> <!-- Homebet -->
                </div>

                <div class="center-betting-input" align="center">
                    <input type="text" name="homebet" class="bets" /><span class="versus">VS</span><input type="text" name="awaybet" class="bets" />
                </div>

                <div class="left-betting-team">
                    <img src="/images/pl-logo-arsnl.png"> <h8 class="centering-teamname2">Arsenal</h8> <!-- Awaybet -->
                </div>      
            </div>

            <div class="extra-betting-bg"> <!-- Just design -->

            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="submit-button-area" align="center">
            <input type="submit" value="" class="submit-button"> <!-- Submit-button -->
        </div>
</form>
```

**FINAL QUESTION**

How would I assign a **gameid** to a `div` or maybe a `<form>` (or what fits the situation best), so it gets registert into the database table "Bets"?

*I wouldn't know, which code-snippet you would need to figure this out, if any is needed.*

**EDIT 1:**

**THE INSERT.PHP-FILE**

```
<?php
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php');

global $wpdb, $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();

$sql= $wpdb->prepare("INSERT INTO `bets` (`userid`, `gameid`, `homebet`, `awaybet`) VALUES (%d, %d, %d, %d)", $current_user->ID, $_POST['gameid'], $_POST['homebet'], $_POST['awaybet']);

$wpdb->query($sql)
?>
```

**EDIT 2** - The modified `Insert.php`-file!

```
<?php
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php');

global $wpdb, $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();

//make sure the bets exist in $_POST
if ((isset($_POST['bets'])) && is_array($_POST['bets'])){
    //loop through the bets getting the gameid and bet information
    foreach($_POST['bets'] as $gameid=>$bet){
        //prepare sql
        $sql= $wpdb->prepare("INSERT INTO `bets` (`userid`, `gameid`, `homebet`, `awaybet`) VALUES (%d, %d, %d, %d)", $current_user->ID, $gameid, $bet['homebet'], $bet['awaybet']);
        //run sql
        $wpdb->query($sql)
    } // This is line 15!
}
?>
```

Comment: The question title is misleading as it asks for something that you are not forced to do and can be done better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on the comments from zebediah49's answer, if you are going to have someone fill out home/away bets for multiple matches on the same page, I suggest you then name your form elements using arrays. something like this:

```
<form action="/scripts/insert.php" method="post" name="gameid"> <!-- Not sure if name="gameid" serves a purpose or just a test - I'm sorry. -->
        <div id="betting-structure">
            <!--Team1 vs Team2-->
            <div class="main-betting-bg">
                <div class="right-betting-team">
                    <h8 class="centering-teamname1">Team1</h8><img src="/images/pl-logo-arsnl.png"> <!-- Homebet -->
                </div>

                <div class="center-betting-input" align="center">
                    <input type="text" name="bets[$gameid][homebet]" class="bets" /><span class="versus">VS</span><input type="text" name="bets[$gameid][awaybet]" class="bets" />
                </div>

                <div class="left-betting-team">
                    <img src="/images/pl-logo-arsnl.png"> <h8 class="centering-teamname2">Team2</h8> <!-- Awaybet -->
                </div>      
            </div>

            <div class="extra-betting-bg"> <!-- Just design -->

            </div>

            <!--Team3 vs Team4-->
            <div class="main-betting-bg">
                <div class="right-betting-team">
                    <h8 class="centering-teamname1">Team3</h8><img src="/images/pl-logo-arsnl.png"> <!-- Homebet -->
                </div>

                <div class="center-betting-input" align="center">
                    <input type="text" name="bets[$gameid][homebet]" class="bets" /><span class="versus">VS</span><input type="text" name="bets[$gameid][awaybet]" class="bets" />
                </div>

                <div class="left-betting-team">
                    <img src="/images/pl-logo-arsnl.png"> <h8 class="centering-teamname2">Team4</h8> <!-- Awaybet -->
                </div>      
            </div>

            <div class="extra-betting-bg"> <!-- Just design -->

            </div>

            <!--Team5 vs Team6-->
            <div class="main-betting-bg">
                <div class="right-betting-team">
                    <h8 class="centering-teamname1">Team5</h8><img src="/images/pl-logo-arsnl.png"> <!-- Homebet -->
                </div>

                <div class="center-betting-input" align="center">
                    <input type="text" name="bets[$gameid][homebet]" class="bets" /><span class="versus">VS</span><input type="text" name="bets[$gameid][awaybet]" class="bets" />
                </div>

                <div class="left-betting-team">
                    <img src="/images/pl-logo-arsnl.png"> <h8 class="centering-teamname2">Team6</h8> <!-- Awaybet -->
                </div>      
            </div>

            <div class="extra-betting-bg"> <!-- Just design -->

            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="submit-button-area" align="center">
            <input type="submit" value="" class="submit-button"> <!-- Submit-button -->
        </div>
</form>
```

Notice, I named the form elements `bets[$gameid][homebet]` and `bets[$gameid][awaybet]`. This requires the gameid be echo'ed by php (so if `$gameid=123` the field will be `bets[123][homebet]` and `bets[123][awaybet]`). Once the form is submitted, it could be handled using a simple foreach loop like so:

```
<?php
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php');

global $wpdb, $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();

//make sure the bets exist in $_POST
if(isset($_POST['bets'] && is_array($_POST['bets'])){
    //loop through the bets getting the gameid and bet information
    foreach($_POST['bets'] as $gameid=>$bet){
        //prepare sql
        $sql= $wpdb->prepare("INSERT INTO `bets` (`userid`, `gameid`, `homebet`, `awaybet`) VALUES (%d, %d, %d, %d)", $current_user->ID, $gameid, $bet['homebet'], $bet['awaybet']);
        //run sql
        $wpdb->query($sql);
    }
}
?>
```

Please note, you will still need to do some validation on the fields to ensure numbers and prevent sql injection.

Comment: Thanks, Jonathan, for clarifying this! Awesome answer!

Comment: I'm getting a `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in ../scripts/insert.php on line 15`. If you'd take a look at `EDIT 2` in my thread, you'll see the modified code. Line 15 is simply just a closing bracket `}`. Please help. How do I get rid of this problem?

Comment: @FrederickAndersen sorry, its just missing a semi colon at the end of the `$wpdb->query($sql)` line.

Comment: I'll have to admit; yours is conclusively the best answer! Do you mind - if not to difficult - answering me on two other small questions? **1.** How would you do - via simple PHP - so it displays an error message if no value is given? **2.** How would you do so the matches displayed is actually snatched from the database table `matches` rather than handwritten? I'd use a `SELECT`-statement (http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp) for it, but I can't seem to mix the SQL-statements together with the HTML/PHP design (the divs, etc). Thanks, Jonathan - a well deserved "Best Answer".

Comment: @FrederickAndersen I could answer the questions, however I am not strong in wordpress as I usually just write my own code. I can help with the queries or things like that but when it comes to wordpress, I'm not sure of the best methods of error handling or the database object. As far as what I can help with, you would want to use a `SELECT` to query some number of matches where the user hasn't already entered a bet. something like `SELECT GameID,Team1Name,Team2Name FROM Games WHERE GameID NOT IN (SELECT GameID FROM Bets WHERE UserID=$userID) LIMIT $limit`. loop over that and display each game.

Comment: I get the drift. I would technically replace that sentence with the long list of PHP-matches, right (it would just remove the design)? If so, how would I put it in? With `<?php` `?>` brackets? Your help is really appreciated, Jonathan!

Comment: I really just need to know, where I'd have to place the line (in which document, etc.).

Comment: @FrederickAndersen run the query (or similar) before the form. that will get you a result with whichever games you need. Then loop over the result and echo out the table with the names of the teams in the <h8> and the game id in the input name. I don't know how to use the wp database object to query so I don't know what the result looks like or how the looping would be done. Usually you would get an object that you can use a `foreach($result as $row)` loop to loop over or a mysql result that you can do a `while($row=$result->fetch_assoc())` loop.

Comment: @FrederickAndersen check this out:http://codex.wordpress.org/wpdb#query_-_Run_Any_Query_on_the_Database

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12577/discussion-between-frederick-andersen-and-jonathan-kuhn)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a hidden `<input>` element:

```
<input type="hidden" name="gameid" value="5280" />
```

EDIT: That way it will show up in your `$_POST` or whatever you're using, just like `homebet` and `awaybet`.

EDIT2: to clarify a question posed in the comment:

```
<?php
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-load.php');

global $wpdb, $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();

for($n=1;$n<=8;$n++) {
    $sql= $wpdb->prepare("INSERT INTO `bets` (`userid`, `gameid`, `homebet`, `awaybet`) VALUES (%d, %d, %d, %d)", $current_user->ID, $_POST["gameid$n"], $_POST["homebet$n"], $_POST["awaybet$n"]);
    $wpdb->query($sql)
}


?>
```

Comment: That seems quite genius, actually. The `value` would be inputted by me then, or would it be called through the `SELECT`-statement?

I've edited the thread, where the `insert.php` now is showcased. Would I implement the `gameid` like that into the file? Thanks, zebediah!

Comment: You put the `value` in when you generated the page.  That is how you do it, but be warned of an injection attack there. (I can edit the page source, and submit whatever I want there, remember).  I think the `%d` should save you, but you should check that.

Comment: The value is put by the script because, way before drawing the form, you MUST query the game data (id, opponents and stuff).

Comment: Awesome, zebediah! As I haven't explained though, the bets-page will consist of a list of active bets, so the user has to input two numbers - corresponding to the goalscorings as explained - in up to 6 different matches. Wouldn't that cause trouble regarding the method, when assigning individuel `gameid`'s?

Comment: In that case you need something a bit different.  In case 1, there is a selector where the user picks which game to bet in (and you use an appropriate input for selecting which game: radio button or drop down or something).  In case 2, you create a form with `gameid$n`, `homebet$n`, and `awaybet$n` triplets.  You then loop across `$n` and process the input from `$_POST["gameid$n"]`, as you have the single one there.  I'm not sure why you'd force the user to do all at once though? (or assume "blank means no bet, so skip this query").

Comment: How would the PHP look like? Would I replace the `name` (homebet, awaybet and gameid) with `gameid$n`, `homebet$n` and `awaybet$n`? I'm sorry to bug you, but I'm quite new at SQL, but I'm desperately trying to learn it. You've received "Best Answer" ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could apply the `gameid` to the URL so it would be something like this:

http://yourdomain.com/betpage/?gameid=123

You would then grab the `gameid` using the `$_GET` method.

```
$gameid = $_GET['gameid'];
```

But remember to sanitize the variable.

Comment: Seems like a good idea, but - as I haven't explained - the bets-page will consist of a list of active bets, so this exact idea might not fit properly, would it? Thanks, David!

Comment: @FrederickAndersen It would, inside the `<form>` element under action you would have the action like this: action="/scripts/insert.php?gameid=123". You would grab the gameid like I described above using `$_GET` inside insert.php

Comment: Okay! So each new match would have its own `<form>`?

Comment: @FrederickAndersen If your listing multiple matches on the same page, then yes.

Comment: Okay, David. I'll give it a try! Thanks for the effort.